# Getting "HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, & config doesn't allow creation .." while execting spring hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, command-line

I am trying to write a simple spring-hibernate **command line application** with transaction management support, but I am constantly getting 
*"org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here"*

my spring config file (applicationContext.xml)

```
    <!-- Context Provider -->
<bean class="com.rps.util.ContextUtil" />
<!-- The transactional service objects -->
<bean id="service" class="com.rps.service.DefaultService" p:parentDao-ref="parentDao" p:childDao-ref="childDao" />

<!--the transactional advice-->
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!--this transactional advice runs for any service method execution-->
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.rps.service..*.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>

<!-- The PlatformTransactionManager -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<!-- The DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OsivTest" p:username="XXX" p:password="YYY" />

<!-- Session Factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/rps/domain/Parent.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/rps/domain/Child.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Data Access Objects -->
<bean id="parentDao" class="com.rps.data.hbm.HibernateParentDao" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
<bean id="childDao" class="com.rps.data.hbm.HibernateChildDao" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

DAO Code (Session Factory object set by IoC container as configured in context file above)

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass()).list();
}
```

DefaultService Class: (parentDao injected from IoC container)

```
public class DefaultService implements Service {

@Override
public List<Parent> getAllParent() {
    return parentDao.findAll();
}
    //Other methods
}
```

Main method code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    Service s = (Service) context.getBean("service");
    s.getAllParent();
}
```

I am using hibernate version 3.1.3 and spring 3. 
How do we configure one session per thread? I believe the issues is that no session is being associated with my execution thread. I was assuming that transaction manager will open a session if not already found, but it does not do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote 1:

> I am using hibernate version 3.1.3 and spring 3

Quote 2:

> **Note**
>   As of Spring 3.0, Spring requires Hibernate 3.2 or later.

([Source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate))

BTW, [the current stable Hibernate version is 3.6.7](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core)

Comment: Thanks ... I will try with the latest versions.